# visual-studio-code: How to disable adding to user path?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time my computer starts it adds the VS Code paths to the user environment path. I have another program that uses Java and apparently has a known bug that prohibits it from seeing the system path when there is a user path.

Is there any way to disable adding to the user path at system startup?

Comment: You probably have it set in your environment as a user or system variable. Go to Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settiings and click on Environment Variables. From there you can remove VS from the PATH.

Comment: I can remove it all I want. The issue is VS Code keeps adding itself back in.